# Vertically align <h2> when rotated 90 degree

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<div class="row">
    <h1>Video</h1>
    <img src="http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2784141.ece/ALTERNATES/s1200/Tom-Cruise-and-Cameron-Diaz.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS→

```
.row h1 {
    font-size: 12.9em;
    transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
}
```

I want that arrangement to look somewhat like this [image: this]

Please help me to that in such a way that when there is no "Video" text or h2 the image takes the whole width.

[Code Pen Link](https://codepen.io/codeispoetry/pen/awLjaM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you will use 2 different classes whether it is an *image* or a *video*, here is how you can make that work, so the image will take full width when there is no "video"

What I simply did were to put the `h1` last in the row, and by doing so, I can target it using the sibling selector `+` and either show or hide it based on which class the previous sibling has.

With a video (simulated with a `video` class)

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
}
.row h1 {
  display: none;
}
.row .video,
.row .image,
.row img {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .video {
  padding-left: 8rem;             /* match font size of h1 */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row .video + h1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 8rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <img class="video" src="http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2784141.ece/ALTERNATES/s1200/Tom-Cruise-and-Cameron-Diaz.jpg" alt="">
  <h1>Video</h1>
</div>
```

---

With an image (lacking the `video` class)

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
}
.row h1 {
  display: none;
}
.row .video,
.row .image,
.row img {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .video {
  padding-left: 8rem;             /* match font size of h1 */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row .video + h1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 8rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <img class="image" src="http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2784141.ece/ALTERNATES/s1200/Tom-Cruise-and-Cameron-Diaz.jpg" alt="">
  <h1>Video</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @AdiYogi Yes, and when you add what I showed it will look perfect...as you haven't yet in that posted link

Comment: I replaced .row with .wrap .content .main-column .inner-row .video, but everything works fine except that H1 is not showing.

Comment: @AdiYogi You need to put it _after_ the image/video...as I did, or else you can't make use of the sibling selector

Comment: ahh I got it now.

Comment: @AdiYogi Also, it will **not** show the _Video_ text unless it is an element with class `video`. If you use the `video` tag you can replace the `.video` class selector in my CSS sample with a `video` type selector, like this `.row video` and `.row video + h1`

Comment: @AdiYogi That gap is caused by the font. You can add a 15px adjustment to the padding and the text's left position, like this (note though, you might have to adjust it based on the font you use): `.row .video { padding-left: calc(8rem - 15px); }` and `.row .video + h1 { left: -15px;`

Comment: This is a very high-level CSS. I assume that you have a minimum of 10 years experience.

Comment: @AdiYogi 23 years to be exact :) ...though technology wise, one can learn it faster, but with time comes how to combine stuff

Comment: I can see that you are Michael Jordan or Mohammad Ali of CSS. Thank you so much we are blessed that you are here on this community. Moreover, You are very polite while helping.

Comment: @AdiYogi Thank you very much ... and at SO there is a full _NBA team_, so always someone to serve

Comment: Is there any property with the help of which we can align it vertically in the middle → https://www.screencast.com/t/PmlQLBpx

Comment: @AdiYogi I will have a look later...will notify you when done

Comment: @AdiYogi If you change these 3 values in the `.row .video + h1` rule, it should do that `top: 50%; transform-origin: top left; transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-50%);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `writing-mode`..

[Writing Mode @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

> The writing-mode property defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically and the direction in which blocks progress.

```css
h1 {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 5em;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

img {
  height: 220px;
}

.row {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1>Video</h1>
  <img src="http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2784141.ece/ALTERNATES/s1200/Tom-Cruise-and-Cameron-Diaz.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: sir, w/o Float.

Comment: If you're adding restrictions you need to [edit] that into your question.

Answer (score 1):

make h1 position:absolute and make it left aligned.give the row some padding on left.

CSS

```
.row{
  position: relative;
  PADDING-LEFT:10em;
}

.row h1 {
    font-size: 12.9em;
    transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row h1 {
  font-size: 12.9em;
  transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
}

.row img {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1>Video</h1>
  <img src="http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2784141.ece/ALTERNATES/s1200/Tom-Cruise-and-Cameron-Diaz.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted.